# Changing the colour of certain ListView columns

Tags: c#, listview, colors, items, subitem

How can I change the colour of a specific column in a listview?

```
string[] row = { appID[i], "Launch Game"}; // more data to add

listView1.Items.Add(nameArray[i], i).SubItems.AddRange(row);

listView1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620120/listview-subitems-font-not-working)

Comment: Another related question is the one to color a single cell which can be found here. [Highlight cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215248/c-sharp-listview-detail-highlight-a-single-cell)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem( "Item 1"); 
item1.SubItems.Add( "Color" ); 
item1.SubItems[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
item1.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false; 
listView1.Items.Add( item1 );
```

If you are using database to bind it you may have to do this during on item databind process.  Let me know if that's the case.