# Change color to Listview column item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is it possible to change color of a specific item for specific column in `Listview` ?

Comment: Exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234910/changing-the-colour-of-certain-listview-columns

Comment: @user2214609 backcolor or forecolor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `ListView` named `ListView1`.

If you know the name of the column you want to change, then try this:

```
foreach(ListViewItem theItem in ListView1)
{
    if(theItem.Text == "Column Name")
    {
        theItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        // You also have access to the list view's SubItems collection
        theItem.SubItems[0].ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

Note: Obviously `Column Name` is made up and you would need to substitute the real column name. Also, `Color.Red` is made up and you can substitute whatever color you want.

Comment: What is exactly 'ListViewItem'? Can you explain that, please? @Karl Anderson

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned what you want to change so Below is the example to change backcolor and forecolor of a specific subitem in listview

```
 item1.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
 item1.SubItems[1].ForeColor= Color.Yellow;
```

You can specify your own subitem by column name.